# Angularfire query where a key does not exist

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have to query for docs where key does not exist in doc in collection

I tried

```
this.dbCollectionService.userCollection.ref.where('socialUserId','==',typeof null).get().then(res => {
      res.forEach(
        documentSnapshot => {
          console.log('in');
          //this.selectedUser$ = this.firestore.doc(documentSnapshot.ref);
         console.log(documentSnapshot.data());
        });
    }).catch(err => {

    });

 this.dbCollectionService.userCollection.ref.where('socialUserId','==',typeof undefined).get().then(res => {
      res.forEach(
        documentSnapshot => {
          console.log('in');
          //this.selectedUser$ = this.firestore.doc(documentSnapshot.ref);
         console.log(documentSnapshot.data());
        });
    }).catch(err => {

    });
```

But both are not working